# Relaunch application if there are exception in the program

Tags: java

I want to create a program that can **relaunch** itself if they detected any **exception error** during the execution.

Let say my program is trying reading a file. If the program failed to read a file, then it will have FileNotFound exception. After this exception occur, the program itself will **restart** and retry it again. This process will continue **3 times** and if the program still cannot read that file, the program will then **terminated** and an exception message will be printed.

I created the read file part, but I have trouble to restart my program if it detect an error. Any help will be appreciated. I have included my pesudo code of what I am trying to do in the relaunch method.

fileReader.java

```
 private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3 ;
    private static final int WAIT_BETWEEN_RETRIES_SEC = 30 ;

    public static void main(String... args) 
    {
        int retry = 1;
        while (retry <= MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                //this method is okay, good. pass to next method.
                readFile();

                //error detected, retry only this method. Error fixed, pass to next method 
                method2();

                //error detected, retry only this method. Error fixed, pass to next method
                method3();
                method4();
                method5();


                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                retry++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_RETRIES_SEC * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            }
        }
        if (retry == MAX_RETRIES) {
            System.out.println("Failed!");
            return;
        }
        // success
    }

  private static void readFile() throws IOException {
     //read file code
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of relaunching, you can (and should) handle this in main(). For example:

```
    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3 ;
    private static final int WAIT_BETWEEN_RETRIES_SEC = 30 ;

    public static void main(String... args) 
    {
        int retry = 1;
        while (retry <= MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                readFile();
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                retry++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_RETRIES_SEC * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            }
        }
        if (retry == MAX_RETRIES) {
            System.out.println("Failed!");
            return;
        }
        // success
    }

  private static void readFile() throws IOException {
     //read file code
  }
```

Comment: After exiting the while loop, `retry == MAX_RETRIES` will always return true; therefore, it can be removed.

Comment: @sharonbon Hi thank you for your respond. I get what you are trying to do. Now what if I have 4 methods. I have updated my answer above. I want to retries only that method has error exception. If no error detected, continue

Comment: you mean you got the idea for one method but still cannot figure how to do it for 4 methods?? really??

Comment: Oh,woops. I wasnt thinking. I think i got it now

Comment: you could show your appriciation for the effort by accepting and/or upvoting my answer...

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, I am wondering what can I do if an error occur in the middle of the method and I only want to retry that method with out trying the entire thing? Let say I have method 1,2,3,4,5 and if method 3 have exception, the program will retry method 3 instead of the entire program from the beginning. Is there a way to do it? Can I do another nested while loop in another method? I have edited the my code

Comment: Your code is correct, I just came up with other idea what if my I have lots of methods in my code and don't want to retry the entire program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88606/discussion-between-amazed-and-sharonbn).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to restart the whole application after unsuccesfully reading a file - just re-run the problematic function (readFile() in this case).

Simply put `readFile()` in your `reLaunch()` function

```
private static void reLaunch(int relaunchAttempt){
readFile();
}
```

Or

```
private static void readFile(){

       try{

        //read file code
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

            //relaunch the application if error detected
           readFile(count);
          e.printStackTrace()
       }
    }
```

Maintain count in `readFile()` function

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use FutureTask under package java.util.concurrent. This support the feature the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class fileReader {

    private static final MAX_RETRY = 3;
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int retry = 0;
        while (retry++ < MAX_RETRY) {
            try {
                readFile();
                break; // Break while loop
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (retry == MAX_RETRY) {
                    // Failed 3 times
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        // Success!
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
    }

    private static void readFile(){ ... }
    private static method1(){ ... }
    private static method2(){ ... }
    private static method3(){ ... }

}
```